# How to override an object's property (which is an array) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object-literal, `options`, and it has a property called `datapoints` that is an array. I am trying to replace this array with one that I am getting from a JSON file (pasted below).

In the `tempactivation` function, I have this code `options.data[0].dataPoints = items;`.

I mean this

```
dataPoints: [
    { x: 5, y: 10 },
    { x: 10, y: 12 },
    { x: 15, y: 8 },
    { x: 20, y: 14 }
]
```

has to be changed, on the `option` object itself, to:

```
dataPoints: [
    {x: 144949, y : 56},
    {x: 144950, y : 12},
    {x: 144951, y : 81},
    {x: 144952, y : 14}
]
```

But, that property is not getting changed values as expected.

Here is the code that I tried.

```
$(function () {
    function waetherName(){
        var thisOut = 'Mon- '+'13/05/2014';
        return thisOut;
    }

    function tempActivation(){
        var items = [];
        $.getJSON( "JSON/Temperature.json", function( data ) {
            $.each(data.Temperature, function( index, value ) {
                items.push(value);
                console.log(value);
                console.log(items[index] + ' Ar');
            });

            options.data[0].dataPoints = items;

            console.log(options.data[0].dataPoints);
        }); 
    }


    tempActivation();


    var options = {
        title: {
            text: "Weather Chart for Bangalore"
        },
        animationEnabled: true,
        data: [
            {
                type: "spline",
                dataPoints: [
                    { x: 5, y: 10 },
                    { x: 10, y: 12 },
                    { x: 15, y: 8 },
                    { x: 20, y: 14 },
                    { x: 25, y: 6 },
                    { x: 30, y: 24 },
                    { x: 35, y: -4 },
                    { x: 40, y: 10 },
                    { x: 45, y: 10 },
                    { x: 50, y: 10 },
                    { x: 55, y: 10 },
                    { x: 60, y: 10 },
                    { x: 65, y: 10 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    options.title.text = waetherName();
});
```

JSON file

```
{    
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "555468b14a86e4cc2fdd62aa"
    },
    "Date": "20150514",
    "Temperature": [    
        {"x": "144949", "y" : "56"},
        {"x": "144950", "y" : "12"},
        {"x": "144951", "y" : "81"},
        {"x": "144952", "y" : "14"},
        {"x": "144953", "y" : "30"},
        {"x": "144954", "y" : "31"},
        {"x": "144955", "y" : "40"},
        {"x": "144956", "y" : "30"},
        {"x": "144957", "y" : "54"},
        {"x": "144958", "y" : "45"},
        {"x": "144959", "y" : "1"},
        {"x": "145000", "y" : "50"},
        {"x": "145001", "y" : "21"},
        {"x": "145002", "y" : "18"},
        {"x": "145003", "y" : "43"},
        {"x": "145004", "y" : "54"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you use such a long way of assigning the entire new array to the property? In your `$.getJSON` callback, this should suffice: `options.data[0].dataPoints = data.Temperature;`

Comment: move `tempActivation();` after `var options`.

Comment: Hi All, I am struggling to get this solved? Any help. Am tried the above one as well.